# How to accomplish elif in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I try to accomplish  if... elif..elif..else... in tensorflow, but some errors occurred. Then I try tf.cond， but it is a singe brunch.

labels is defined as a placeholder, it is a tensor that needs to be fed when training. The range of labels and newlogits is [0,27], but when computing accuracy, I want to map the labels and the logits to [0,3].

```
   def tower_acc(logits, labels, batch_size):
       newlogits=tf.argmax(logits,1)
       resultlabels =[]
       resultlogits =[]
      for i in range(batch_size):
            if labels[i]<=4:
                tmplabel=0
           elif 5<labels[i]<=9:
                tmplabel=1
           elif 10<labels[i]<=14:
                tmplabel=2
           else:
                tmplabel=3
           resultlabels.append(tmplabel)
      for i in range(batch_size):
           if newlogits[i]<=4:
                tmplogit=0
           elif 5<newlogits[i]<=9:
                tmplogit=1
           elif 10<newlogits[i]<=14:
                tmplogit=2
           else:
                tmplogit=3
           resultlogits.append(tmplogit)
       correct_pred = tf.equal(resultlogits, resultlabels)
       accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
       return accuracy
```

The error is the following:
  raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to review Tensorflow basics.

Like the error says, you cannot treat Tensorflow tensors as Python booleans. `label[i]<4` is a (boolean) tensorflow tensor. Think about it as a pointer into your Tensorflow graph - it doesn't have a value by itself (in your case, its value is obviously dependent on the placeholder you feed). Another problem with your code is that Tensorflow doesn't support `a<x<b` notation (you would need `tf.logical_and` for that).

While in priniciple, it is possible to nest tf.cond operations by using an inner `tf.cond` within the `false_fn` of an outer `tf.cond`, your entire approach to remapping integers is inappropriate - by using a for loop and ifs, you are trying to force the gpu to work serially.

Instead, define a lookup table with 28 elements, mapping each integer to 0, 1, 2 or 3 and use ['tf.gather'](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to map all of the labels from their 28-class representation to a 4-class representation. This mapping can be done at the same time for all of the labels, no loops needed.